# How to populate columns using values from multiple rows of another sheet (Excel)

Tags: excel, lookup

I'm not sure what to search for this.

Basically, say I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
A | apple     | 1
A | aardvark  | 1
A | alternate | 3
B | bear      | 2
B | banana    | 4
C | candy     | 3
C | carnivore | 2
```

and I want to copy values into another sheet so that it looks like this:

```
A | apple | 1 | aardvark  | 1 | alternate | 3
B | bear  | 2 | banana    | 4 |           | 
C | candy | 3 | carnivore | 2 |           |
```

I know there's the lookup function, but I'm not sure how to make it select the first, second, third etc. instance of what's being referenced.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the screenshot below, use the following formulas:

`E2`: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$8,MATCH(E1,$A$1:$A$8,0)+COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,E1)),"")`

`F2`:

```
=IF(INT(COLUMNS($F$1:F$1)/2)<COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,$E2),INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH($E2,$A$2:$A$8,0)+INT(COLUMNS($F$1:F$1)/2)),"")
```

`G2`:

```
=IF(INT(COLUMNS($G$1:G$1)/2)<COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,$E2),INDEX($C$2:$C$8,MATCH($E2,$A$2:$A$8,0)+INT(COLUMNS($G$1:G$1)/2)),"")
```

Select `F2` and `G2`, and fill to the right as far as you need, then fill the entire table down as far as you need.

[image]

Comment: **Edit:** Never mind! I didn't notice the last range didn't have a dollar sign. Thank you! || ------------ ||

Thank you for your response. I'm trying to wrap my head around this a little so I can match it to my sheet; I replaced each of the ranges with the cells that match the corresponding information I need but the first row just gives me info from the same terms. Using this example, it's essentially giving me: 

``A | apple | 1 | apple | 1``